# sas convert date format

Tags: date, format, sas

I have a var of birth date in this format: 15APR1954
I need to set a new var that will present the current age - as if today's date is 01.01.2011
in order to use the var, how do I convert the date? 
otherwise it gives me the following error :"The MDY function call does not have enough arguments".

```
data DAT2;set DAT1;
array BD{*} birth_date;
Curage=0;
do i=1 to dim(BD);
Curage+(MDY(01012011)-(birth_date));
end;
drop i;
run;
```

Comment: Are you specifically looking for age as of 1/1/YYYY or is that just a placeholder and could be any date during the year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to calculate age is to use the SAS built-in function [`yrdif()`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/67398/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1pmmr2dtec32an1vbsqmm3abil5.htm).

```
data dat2;
    set dat1;
    curage = yrdif(birth_date, today(), 'AGE');
run;
```

The function `today()` returns today's date. If you want the age as of a certain date, e.g. 2011-01-01 like in your example, you can replace `today()` with `'01JAN2011'd` or with `mdy(1, 1, 2011)`. (Note that your syntax for [`mdy()`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0bo5thbfrcab1n1menkqxq2suiv.htm) was incorrect.)

I'll also note that your array approach doesn't make a whole lot of sense; you're defining an array with only one element, so you might as well just perform operations on that value. Arrays are useful when you wish to perform identical operations to a *group* of 2 or more variables. For thorough information on array processing in SAS, see [this section of the documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/67885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1i7zlvukj8arhn1ihivqz9mot9m.htm).

Comment: thank you, it worked out as you said. could you maybe refer me to a good explanation regarding arrays usage? I found a lot but as you mentioned that it does not make much sense, I might have not understood it completely.

Comment: @user3581800: Added a link to information about arrays to the answer.

Comment: Nice answer and explanation. There were some previous problems with using YRDIF, but as you show using the 'AGE' option, which was introduced in 9.3 (http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2011/07/12/computing-age-in-sas-9-3/) it works as assumed now.